# Spring REST: redirect and show view

Tags: java, spring, rest

I would like to write Controller which will receive email as parameter, find user by email and show view with this user's profile by url where parameter would be nick.

Here are my controller for getting user by email (example):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> getByEmail(@RequestParam String email) {
        User user = userDao.getUserByEmail(email);
        return Optional.ofNullable(user)
              .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(
                      result, HttpStatus.OK))
              .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

So, here I could get user's information if JSON format. **But what I want to get should looks like:**

1. User access url for `/profile?email=foo@email` (It could be controller or view, idk)
2. Then, user redirected to url `/usernick` and gets view with the profile information.

*Again: `/profile?email=foo@email` -> `/usernick` -> User is happy as he could see his profile*

I am using jQuery and html on client side of application. How could I resolve it?

**One more question:** I read that it's good way to use REST for only CRUD operations, it that true?
For example, is it ok to use `modelAndView` etc?

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close, but this is fairly opinionated, and it might be better for Programmers.

Comment: @chrylis what do you mean?